# Prevent duplicate entries in a database table based on 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, unique, alter-table

I record the datas of a competition in an MySQL database.

I need to have unique entry for each player so i’ve done this :

```
alter table xtu_datas_competition add unique index(email);
```

It works perfectly.

But there are several competitions, so i have also a colum id_ competition and i want to have unique entry for email and for specific colum id_ competition

For example :

```
2 identical email for 2 identical colum id_ competition : duplicate
2 identical email  for 2 different colum id_ competition : not duplicate
```

How can i adapt my previous code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have to define a unique constraint containing both columns:

```
alter table xtu_datas_competition add unique index(id_competition,email);
```

Hope this will help you.